VBA Sort Category Range and Part Range in Alphabetical order
I am making an inventory list for various parts so we can order replacements more easily. These parts are sorted into categories so the whole sheet is similar to the example here.
Example

I laid out the sheet like this so it is easier to read, and I would greatly prefer to not change this layout because I have almost a dozen other userforms and other code that reference the data using this layout.
My problem now is I want to be able to sort the categories alphabetically, while also moving all the parts in that category. I also want to be able to sort all the parts within a category and have the vendor and price info move with their associated parts.
I am new to VBA, so I am not sure how best to do this. My current best idea is to define a range or array using the part or category as the name, sort the array names alphabetically, and then reinsert the array values into the sheet in the new order.
Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.
I am new to VBA, so I am not sure how best to do this. My current best idea is to define a range or array using the part or category as the name, sort the array names alphabetically, and then reinsert the array values into the sheet in the new order.
Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

This statement by @EvilBlueMonkey in his answer deserves close attention: consider a better way to store your data in a machine-friendly way and to use a separated sheet to display them in a user-friendly way

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no need for VBA. A couple of extra columns will do the trick. Copy this in a new sheet:



Category
Part
Vendor
Price
Category index
Category Sub-Index




Car



=IF(A2="",E1,A2)
=IF(E2=E1,F1+1,1)



Engine


=IF(A3="",E2,A3)
=IF(E3=E2,F2+1,1)




MG
$
=IF(A4="",E3,A4)
=IF(E4=E3,F3+1,1)



Tire


=IF(A5="",E4,A5)
=IF(E5=E4,F4+1,1)




Michelin
$
=IF(A6="",E5,A6)
=IF(E6=E5,F5+1,1)




Continental
$
=IF(A7="",E6,A7)
=IF(E7=E6,F6+1,1)


Airplane



=IF(A8="",E7,A8)
=IF(E8=E7,F7+1,1)



Wings


=IF(A9="",E8,A9)
=IF(E9=E8,F8+1,1)




Boeing
$
=IF(A10="",E9,A10)
=IF(E10=E9,F9+1,1)




Airbus
$
=IF(A11="",E10,A11)
=IF(E11=E10,F10+1,1)



Now copy-paste the values of columns E and F. You'll get this:



Category
Part
Vendor
Price
Category index
Category Sub-Index




Car



Car
1



Engine


Car
2




MG
$
Car
3



Tire


Car
4




Michelin
$
Car
5




Continental
$
Car
6


Airplane



Airplane
1



Wings


Airplane
2




Boeing
$
Airplane
3




Airbus
$
Airplane
4



Now select the whole range and order it by column E and then column F. Column F is technically not necessary since ordering by column E should not change the original order of the data, but bettere safe than sorry.
Needless to say: you can use the same trick via VBA. Ye, it's not sophisticated nor elegant, but it will do the trick without any unecessary extra work. Here an example:
Sub SubSort()
    
    Dim RngTopLeftCell As Range
    Dim RngLastColumn As Range
    Dim StrString As String
    
    Set RngTopLeftCell = Range("A1")
    Set RngLastColumn = Range("D2")
    Set RngLastColumn = Range(RngLastColumn, Cells(Rows.Count, RngLastColumn.Column).End(xlUp))
    
    RngLastColumn.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    RngLastColumn.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    
    Set RngLastColumn = RngLastColumn.Offset(0, 1)
    
    RngLastColumn.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]="""",R[-1]C,RC[-4])"
    
    RngLastColumn.Value2 = RngLastColumn.Value2
    
    Set RngLastColumn = RngLastColumn.Offset(0, 1)
    
    RngLastColumn.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=R[-1]C[-1],R[-1]C+1,1)"
    
    RngLastColumn.Value2 = RngLastColumn.Value2
    
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=RngLastColumn.Offset(0, -1), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=RngLastColumn, _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
        .SetRange Range(RngTopLeftCell, RngLastColumn)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        
        .SortFields.Clear
    End With
    
    RngLastColumn.EntireColumn.Offset(0, -1).Delete
    RngLastColumn.EntireColumn.Delete
    
End Sub

Then again: consider a better way to store your data in a machine-friendly way and to use a separated sheet to display them in a user-friendly way.

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)(Note that this method also sorts the Vendors)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

let

//change next line to reflect actual data type
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Category", type text}, {"Part", type text}, {"Vendor", type text}, {"Price", Int64.Type}}),

//Convert to more usable format for sorting
//Group by Category, then subgroup by Part
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Category"}, {
        {"all Part", (t)=>
            Table.Group(t,{"Part"},{
                {"all2", each Table.Sort(_,{"Part"}), type table}},
            GroupKind.Local,(x,y)=>Number.From(y[Part]<>null)), 
            type table[Part=nullable text, all2=table[Vendor=nullable text, Price=nullable number]]}},
        GroupKind.Local,(x,y)=>Number.From(y[Category]<> null)),
    
//Expand groups and sort
    #"Expanded all Part" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "all Part", {"Part", "all2"}),
    #"Expanded all2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded all Part", "all2", {"Vendor", "Price"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded all2",{{"Category", Order.Ascending}, {"Part", Order.Ascending}, {"Vendor", Order.Ascending}}),

//Return to original format by
//replacing repeated Category and Part with nulls
    //Add index column to allow referring to previous row
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Null Category Rows" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Added Index",
        each [Index],
        each [Category],
        (x,y,z)=> if #"Added Index"{y-1}[Category] = z then null else x,
        {"Category"}),
    #"Null Part Rows" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Null Category Rows",
        each [Index],
        each [Part],
        (x,y,z)=> if #"Added Index"{y-1}[Part] = z then null else x,
        {"Part"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Null Part Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"



Is this VBA code? I tried to copy it, but none of it would read. Also, I am using Microsoft 365. Not sure if that makes a difference.

@GFRED262 Please read the bullet list under to use power query and follow those instructions. What do you mean by none of it would read? And power query is not VBA but it is available in versions of Excel since 2010 as I wrote.
